# Play Scala Activator Server having errors while serving requests because of @Inject not working

Tags: java, scala, playframework, jvm

I installed Scala and Activator via Brew on Mac OS. The Activator server run fine and displays following message:-

```
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

The server runs fine and gives response for controller:-

```
class Catalog extends Controller {
  var ws: WSClient = null
  def inStock() = Action.async { implicit request =>
    val url = "http://some.uri.com/random"
    val request : WSRequest = ws.url(url)
    request.withQueryString("productId" -> "1234").get().map { response =>
      Ok(response.json)
    }
  }
}
```

But when I hit the request via browser at url (localhost:9000/) after altering the controller as:-

```
class Catalog @Inject() (ws: WSClient) extends Controller {
   def inStock() = Action.async { implicit request =>
        val url = "http://some.uri.com/random"
        val request : WSRequest = ws.url(url)
        request.withQueryString("productId" -> "1234").get().map { response =>
          Ok(response.json)
        }
      }
    }
```

It throws error given below:

```
    Error in custom provider, java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "port"
          while locating play.api.libs.ws.ning.WSClientProvider
          at play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSModule.bindings(NingWS.scala:456):
        Binding(interface play.api.libs.ws.WSClient to Pro

viderConstructionTarget(class play.api.libs.ws.ning.WSClientProvider) in interface javax.inject.Singleton) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
      while locating play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
        for parameter 0 at controllers.api.v1.Users.<init>(Users.scala:17)
      while locating controllers.api.v1.Users
        for parameter 6 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:47)
      while locating router.Routes
      while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
      while locating play.api.routing.Router
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "port"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
        at com.ning.http.util.ProxyUtils.createProxyServerSelector(ProxyUtils.java:160)
        at com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig$Builder.build(AsyncHttpClientConfig.java:1000)
        at play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingAsyncHttpClientConfigBuilder.build(NingConfig.scala:147)
        at play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSClient$.apply(NingWS.scala:72)
        at play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSAPI.client$lzycompute(NingWS.scala:480)
        at play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSAPI.client(NingWS.scala:470)
        at play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSAPI.client(NingWS.scala:466)
        at play.api.libs.ws.ning.WSClientProvider.get(NingWS.scala:462)
        at play.api.libs.ws.ning.WSClientProvider.get(NingWS.scala:461)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:321)
        at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:69)
        at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$$anonfun$2.apply(BuiltinModule.scala:69)
        at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:158)
        at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get$lzycompute(BuiltinModule.scala:69)
        at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:65)
        at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider.get(BuiltinModule.scala:64)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
        at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:321)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:316)
        at play.api.Application$class.routes(Application.scala:112)
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.routes(Application.scala:241)
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:90)
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:87)
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:87)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
        at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:156)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)
        at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:119)
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:111)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

    5 errors
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:321) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:316) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at play.api.Application$class.routes(Application.scala:112) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.routes(Application.scala:241) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:90) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:87) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:87) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:156) ~[play-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        ... 14 common frames omitted



Following is application.conf

    # This is the main configuration file for the application.
    # ~~~~~

    # Secret key
    # ~~~~~
    # The secret key is used to secure cryptographics functions.
    #
    # This must be changed for production, but we recommend not changing it in this file.
    #
    # See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ApplicationSecret for more details.
    play.crypto.secret = "changeme"

    # The application languages
    # ~~~~~
    play.i18n.langs = [ "en" ]

    # Router
    # ~~~~~
    # Define the Router object to use for this application.
    # This router will be looked up first when the application is starting up,
    # so make sure this is the entry point.
    # Furthermore, it's assumed your route file is named properly.
    # So for an application router like `my.application.Router`,
    # you may need to define a router file `conf/my.application.routes`.
    # Default to Routes in the root package (and conf/routes)
    # play.http.router = my.application.Routes

    # Database configuration
    # ~~~~~
    # You can declare as many datasources as you want.
    # By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
    #
    # db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
    # db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
    # db.default.username=sa
    # db.default.password=""

    # Evolutions
    # ~~~~~
    # You can disable evolutions if needed
    # play.evolutions.enabled=false

    # You can disable evolutions for a specific datasource if necessary
    # play.evolutions.db.default.enabled=false
```

Kindly Help!

Comment: Have you checked your `application.conf` to see what is the port there?

Comment: @manub its using the default port, added the `application.conf`

Comment: It looks like you gave play a port that is not a number. Therefore the NumberFormatException. Do you use `-Dhttp.port=1234`?

Comment: @Kris I tried `activator run -Dhttp.port=9090` but the same result at localhost:9090

Answer (score 0):

The error message looks wrong if the `@Inject` is the only thing changing. Are you sure everything "works" without the `@Inject` annotation?

Anyway, the recommended way to declare a dependency to be injected is:

```
class Catalog @Inject() (ws: WSClient) extends Controller {
  def inStock() = Action.async { implicit request =>
    val url = "http://some.uri.com/random"
    val request : WSRequest = ws.url(url)
    request.withQueryString("productId" -> "1234").get().map { response =>
      Ok(response.json)
    }
  }
}
```